# Why is my replay button not working in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I am making a replay button when my player loses on the game over screen. However, when I press replay, the screen appears for split second and then the game over screen reappears. I know I somehow have to make game_over = False, but I can't figure that out. Can anyone fix this?
NOTE: Not all of the code is included, such as code in the button class "**init**", game_over_screen design, etc.

```py
class Button(object):

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(mouse)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and command is not None:
            if self.hovered:
                if command == 'play':
                    game_loop()
                elif command == 'quit':
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                elif command == 'instructions':
                    instructions()
                elif command == 'credits':
                    credits()
                elif command == 'back':
                    start_screen()

def game_over_screen():

    b_play = Button("Replay", 55, WHITE, 180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE)

    game_over = True

    while game_over:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            b_play.handle_event(events, 'play')

        b_play.update()

        b_play.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()


def game_loop():  # Game loop

    game_over = False

    running = True

    while running:

        clock.tick(FPS)
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for events in events:
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # shows game over screen and resets stats and graphics
        if game_over:
            game_over_screen()
            game_over = False
            global all_sprites, mobs, bullets, powerups, player, score
            all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
            mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
            bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
            powerups = pygame.sprite.Group()
            player = Player()
            all_sprites.add(player)
            for i in range(8):
                newmob()
            score = 0
```

Comment: do use the same name in `for events in events:`. In all tutorials you may see `for `event` without `s` because it keeps only one event . And then you will have different names `for event in events:`

Comment: if something doesn't work then put `print()` in many different places - and print values in variable and information which part of code is executed. This way you will see what is going on in code. It is called "print debugging". OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: I see one problem: `game_loop` runs `game_over_screen` which should use `return` to go back to `game_loop` and continue code inside `if game_over:` - and reset all varaibles. But instead of `return` it runs again `game_loop` which use `game_over = False` and later start `while running` but it doesn't reset other variables (ie. Player's energy) and these variables can ends game sooner then you expected and it can run `game_over_screen`.

Comment: in some situations button shouldn't run function but use return value which inform `game_over_screen` to use `return` to go back to `game_loop`

Comment: So basically when I call return, my program returns back to the game loop()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem but I see some problem: `game_loop` runs `game_over_screen` which should use `return` to go back to `game_loop` and it should continue code inside `if game_over:` and reset all varaibles. But instead of returning to previous place it runs again `game_loop` from beginning and it resets only  `game_over = False` and it starts `while running`-loop. But it didn't reset other variables (ie. Player's energy) so these variables can ends game sooner then you expected. And it can run `game_over_screen` again so fast.

Button should have command `return` which doesn't run function but returns `True`

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and command is not None:
        if self.hovered:
            if command == 'play':
                game_loop()
            elif command == 'quit':
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif command == 'instructions':
                instructions()
            elif command == 'credits':
                credits()
            elif command == 'back':
                start_screen()
            elif command == 'return':
                return True
```

and then you can use `True` to return to previous function

```
if b_play.handle_event(events, 'return') is True:
     return
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I don't really understand the logic behind the answer. Could you please explain?

Comment: in `game_loop()` you have `if game_over: game_over_screen() other_commands()`. SO you run `game_over_screen()` and you expect it will run `other_commands()`  after `game_over_screen()`. And `return` in `game_over_screen()` will go back to this place to run `other_commands().`. If you run `game_over()` in `game_over_screen()` then it will no go back to this place but it will run `game_over_screen()` from the beginning - from its first line. And this is not expected situation.